# how to test angular service injected in another service

Tags: angular5, karma-jasmine

i am testing a service in angular(1.6.3)
My service is dependent on another service.
every time i run ng test i get no provider for ServiceName or HTTpclient
any help????
service:

```
export class TraitsService {


 constructor(private gs: GenericService) {}

  getAll(callback: Function) {
    this.gs
      .callGet(`${environment.serviceURL}${environment.serviceConfigAPI.getMyTraits}?active=true`)
      .subscribe(traits => callback(this.flatten(traits)));
  }
```

test:

```
describe('TraitsService', () => {
  let service: TraitsService;
  let gs: GenericService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [TraitsService, GenericService]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(TraitsService);
    gs = TestBed.get(GenericService);
  });

  it('should be created', inject([TraitsService], (service: TraitsService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is dealt with extensively in the [Official Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#services-with-dependencies), but it can be a bit intimidating to start with.  :)

As the documentation points out, there are many ways you can test this.  I personally tend to prefer spying on the original service to test the one under consideration in isolation.  I have put together a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53667126?file=app%2Fmy.service.spec.ts) for you to demonstrate how you could do this in your case.

From that Stackblitz, here is the `describe()` function in the .spec file:

```
describe('TraitsService', () => {
    const mockReturnValue = [1, 2, 3]; // change this!
    const gsSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('GenericService', ['callGet']);
    gsSpy.callGet.and.returnValue(of(mockReturnValue));
    let service: TraitsService;
    // let gs: GenericService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                TraitsService, 
                { provide: GenericService, useValue: gsSpy }
            ]
        });
        service = TestBed.get(TraitsService);
        // gs = TestBed.get(GenericService);
    });

    it('should be created', inject([TraitsService], (service: TraitsService) => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

You can see in the Stackblitz that the service creates correctly.  I hope this helps.

Comment: In a similar setup and identical approach, instead of `gsSpy`, another instance of `GenericService` is injected in my SUT. If I break in the constructor, I can see my spy as an anonymous object, but I also see that the injector has a "proper" instance of `GenericService`, which ends up being used instead of my spy. What could be registering an instance of `GenericService`? Asking in general, looking for pointers where to look. I tried looking at the test harness bootstrapping and just can't see anything else other than my `describe`, registering that dependency